# Does the feat Quick Draw also allow quick sheathing?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

When a creature takes a free action to use the feat [Quick Draw](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/quick-draw-combat-final/) to draw a weapon, does the feat Quick Draw also allow replacing in its sheath any weapon the creature's already wielding as part of that free action?

If not, what sort of action is it to switch weapons *without* dropping either one?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Quick Draw](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/quick-draw-combat---final).

The benefits don't mention putting away anything. I have always used this as a draw only feat, as I believe it's been that way pretty much since 3.0. Now, as you mentioned, that doesn't preclude you from using a free/swift action to drop your weapon, and quick draw a different one. But by default, if you want to put your weapon away, you must take a [move action](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Draw-or-Sheathe-a-Weapon) to do so.

Comment: Get Mixed Combat
Allows you to sheathe as a free action

Answer (score -1):

in the APG page 179 under Quick draw Shield it does give some info on the mechanics,and does state:If you have the quick draw feat,you may don or put away a quick draw shield as a free action.It also says If you have a base attack bonus of +1 or higher,you may don or put away a quick draw shield as a swift action combined with a regular move.I'd rule a weapon is easier to sheath then to take off a quick draw shield but that's for you and your GM to decide

Answer (score -5):

simple solution, with Quick Draw, make sheathing a Swift Action, tada, solved.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Utomneian, could you unpack this a bit? Take a look at our [FAQ].

Comment: -1 Please explain how to turn sheathing into a swift action. I'll remove my downvote once this answer explains that. If it's just a house ruling, and not possible via RAW, that isn't really helpful (because you could just immediately resolve the entire issue via houserules by saying Quick Draw lets you quickly swap).